# Optimize randomization of a number excluding a list of values in Python

Tags: python, random

I need to generate a random number between a min and a max. This number should be a multiple of 10.
This is the solution I have come to.

```
import random
BLOCK = 10

def random_excluding_values(_min, _max, exclude_list):
while True:
    random_number = round(random.randrange(_min, _max - BLOCK) / BLOCK) * BLOCK
    if random_number not in exclude_list:
        return random_number
```

There is a way to obtain the same result using list list comprehension or something else?

Comment: Hint: multiply by 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lower bound includes multiples of 10 when calculating `range`.Skipping while loop makkes sure that you will not be stuck in infinite loop. Conversion to sets make sure that you know what you can get .

```py
import random

def random_excluding_values(_min, _max, exclude_list, num_of_elems):
    lower_bound = round(_min+4, -1)    
    all_nums = {num for num in range(lower_bound, _max+1, 10)}

    exclude_set = set(exclude_list)
    valid_choices = all_nums - exclude_set
    
    return random.sample(valid_choices, num_of_elems)


_min = 9
_max = 103
exclude_list = [40,50,60,70]
#valid_list = [10,20,30,80,90,100]
num_elems = 3 

for i in range(5):
    print(f'run = {i}; result = {random_excluding_values(_min, _max, exclude_list, num_elems)}')
```

Outputs:

```
run = 0; result = [80, 30, 20]
run = 1; result = [10, 20, 80]
run = 2; result = [10, 80, 30]
run = 3; result = [100, 90, 10]
run = 4; result = [10, 20, 100]
```

`random.sample` returns a list of choices from valid set of numbers. So you can easily modify to get you single number.

```py
return random.sample(valid_choices, 1)[0]
```